# Intersecting a projectively normal variety and a hyperplane

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $M$ is a projectively normal projective variety in $\mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}^n$ and we intersect it with a hyperplane $\mathrm{P}V \subseteq \mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}^n$, is the result $M \cap \mathrm{P}V$ a projectively normal variety in the projective space $\mathrm{P}V$?

(This intersection is called a [hyperplane section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_section).)

Answer (score 3):

Not necessary. For instance, if $M$ is a surface then any its singular hyperplane section is not normal (because it is singular in codimension 1).

Comment: Thanks!  Is it true that if $M$ is linearly normal than any of its hyperplane sections is linearly normal?

Comment: No, this is still not true in general --- if $h^1(M,O_M) > h^1(M,O_M(1))$ and $M' \subset M$ is a hyperplane section then the map $H^0(M,O_M(1)) \to H_0(M',O_{M'}(1))$ is not surjective, hence $M'$ is not linearly normal.